# Mixing SSL and non-SSL content in an Apache2 virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

I have a (hopefully) common scenario for one of my sites that I just can't seem to figure out how to deploy correctly.

I have the following site and directories for example.com:

These need to require SSL:

- /var/www/example.com/admin
- /var/www/example.com/order

These need to be non-SSL:

- /var/www/example.com/maps

These need to support both:

- /var/www/example.com/css
- /var/www/example.com/js
- /var/www/example.com/img

I have two virtual host declarations for example.com in my /sites-available/example.com file; the top one is *:443 the second one is *:80.

Since I have two vhost declarations, if a request comes in on 443, the top virtualhost is used, same with the bottom if it's a port 80 request.

However, I can't seem to enforce my SSL requirements using SSLRequireSSL because I'm assuming a port 80 request to /admin or /order is not even hitting the *:443 vhost.

Should I just Deny All to /order and /admin within the *:80 virtual host so that if you try to request it on 80, you'll get a 403 Forbidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better yet, redirect it to ssl (or back) automatically

in non ssl vhost:

```
Redirect /admin https://example.com/admin
Redirect /admin https://example.com/order
```

in ssl vhost (if you really want /maps always to be non-ssl, to save cpu maybe?)

```
Redirect /maps http://example.com/maps
```

Comment: /maps pages use Google Static Maps, and without Premier (too much $$$), SSL is not supported so IE throws non-SSL content warnings.

That's definitely a more friendly way of doing it; thanks.